# htmlencode causes lockup asp.net

Tags: asp.net, internationalization, html-encode

I had text I was displaying as html and I had filtered the content with htmlencode.

When I changed the control to a textbox, I left the htmlencode code alone and it mostly worked.   However, when there were international characters, e.g. éúáó, the ajax calls on the page stopped working.  The page actually displayed properly and there were no errors - javascript or otherwise, but the page effectively stopped working.

I removed the htmlencode and now everything works correctly.  The app is defined as utf-8.

I'm just curious if anyone understands what happened.

Comment: Do you have made custom ajax calls ? Probably you need to encode your ajax post because maybe some characters break the url post.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your Ajax calls use the HTTP GET method and that you were using HTML encoding instead of URL encoding. So perhaps your URLs that got built from your Ajax calls contained characters such as `&acute;` (the HTML encoding for `é`) when they included accented characters, and these broke your URL scheme which caused the request never to make it to your server-side controller. The URL encoding for `é` is actually `%E9`. URL encoding and HTML encoding are different.

When you removed your HtmlEncode call, I guess it fixed your issue with `&` breaking the URL scheme. If I'm correct so far it may be a good idea to change the Ajax calls to use HTTP POST instead of HTTP GET, to be sure you eliminate any other URL issue.

Comment: Well - I'm not sure if your theory is right, but it seems plausible.